# how to convince emacs to stay on the same frame when changing buffers?

Tags: emacs

I like to use emacsclient to open new emacs frames on different virtual desktops. This works great except that its a pain when emacs decides to switch frames if I am switching to a buffer that is already open in a frame other than that has the focus. Is there a way to disable this frame reuse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to customize the behaviour of `display-buffer` (This is the function called by `switch-to-buffer` and friends). The second optional argument `FRAME` needs to be set to `nil` so that the function will only consider the current frame when looking for already open buffers. Also make sure to have `display-buffer-reuse-frames` set to `nil` (It's the default).

Check the built-in documentation: `C-h f display-buffer RET`

Unfortunately, `display-buffer` is often not called directly. Probably remapping `switch-to-buffer` to your custom `switch-to-buffer` will be the best course of action.

Comment: thanks, the display-buffer help led me to the iswitchb code which actually already provides a customization hook into the default buffer switching strategy. `(setq iswitchb-default-method  'samewindow)` seems to do what I want.